# How to deal with different "misplaced view" warnings on every machine?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, warnings

What is causing them? How to get rid of them?

Create a storyboard, add some views. There are no warnings, so store/commit it.

When you open it on another dev machine, there is a chance, it will complain about "misplaced views". You can do the suggested quickfix to resolve it, but if you go back to the first machine, it will complain in the opposite direction.

[image: screenshot]

I think it has to deal with the status bars, in this screenshot you see y=64 instead of y=44, but why!? It's the same project on both machines.

Anything I can set to make it behave the same everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: Your other developer may have a different xCode with different set of warnings.

2: xCode constraint warnings may look mysterious but actually it's doing it's best to keep you alerted. When autolayout can not decide where a view should be placed, like left or right side of the parent view THEN it will try to warn you once by putting it on the left side then once by putting the view on the right side. Same goes for warnings..

DO THIS: before you end working, go through all the **Size Classes** and make sure you have 0 warnings left in any of the Size class.

BTW: that top constraint is sometimes sticking to a status bar height (20px) and sometimes not. Stick it to something else. Maybe setting the statusBar settings as "Inferred" would help.

**How to work your way through the size classes**
You start out with Any x Any size class -> setup all the constraints -> now start switching size classes -> if everything fits (no warning) even on the smallest device in Landscape mode THEN you are ok.

If something not fits or you want a bottom view bigger UIView on iPads for example THEN you switch from Any x Any to Regular x Regular (or where the warning is) -> and alter the same constraint just for that specific size class. "Install constraint" the UI says. U can add custom UI elements too btw.

See image, I have a bigger height for the bottom view in Regular x Regular (iPad landscape/portaite):
[image]

The result will be that now and in the future you are almost 100% adoptable to any device size that will appear on the markets = less maintenance time :)

vote up :)

Comment: The whole storyboard is without warnings on machine one, and it's the same Xcode version on both machines. Strangly the height seems different on both machines, 536 instead of 443. Where could this come from?

Comment: status bar height is 20px. I sure it's the root of problem. When device is rotated to landscape then the statusbar is hidden by default. Maybe that is what it's trying to tell you? Can u post and image of the constraint settings?

Comment: Wow, switching size classes I found a version that has 0 warnings, the other machine must have wCompact-hAny activated. I think you're DO THIS is the right direction, could you add some info how? But If I update frames in one, it will break in another?

Comment: Switching to wRegular it says expected width 800, actual 600. But I have an equal-widths constraint on it. Why is it not updated? Where could I learn more about it and your suggestion to go through all classes to fix it?